# Change access cache folder / prod under debian8 jessie

Tags: apache

I am trying to put my symfony project on a server so you start (debian8 jessie). But I have problem because it is impossible to put the access rights to my folder cache / prod to 777. File has a right 755. I tried with fillzilla and also command line nothing works. help.

Comment: Do you mean you cant change file permissions?

Comment: When I change the rights I put them at 777, it automatically returns to 755

Comment: What commands did you try exactly? Post in Ur question.

Comment: With filzilla just a right click on the folder and the rights are adjustable is what I did I also typed this command chmod -R 777 prod / placing me in the folder ... / cache